# Python readlines Api takes long time while accessing from serial port

Tags: python, linux, time, serial-port, pyserial

I have 12 serial devices connected to my PC , To read just one value from a device take nearly ~4 seconds and the below snippet is taking total of approximately ~1 min to read all the values. Is their a way to optimize the below python script or with other API's which can take less time to serially access the device and read value

Code Snippet:

```
if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        for sfiles in glob.glob('/dev/serial/by-id/usb-XXXXdevNAME*'):
            try:
                s = serial.Serial(sfiles, 9600, timeout=2)
                s.write('XXXdeviceCommandToReadValue XXXX\r\n')
                response = s.readlines() // from the profiles it looks readlines is using more time
```

Profiler results :

```
    16309 function calls (16306 primitive calls) in 54.605 seconds Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.001    0.001   54.605   54.605 /opt/lnx_attenTool/att_devices.py:49(scan_devices)
   12    0.009    0.001   54.522    4.543 {method 'readlines' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
 2136    0.020    0.000   54.513    0.026 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py:439(read)
 2136   54.482    0.026   54.482    0.026 {select.select}
   24    0.000    0.000    0.072    0.003 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py:419(close)
   12    0.072    0.006    0.072    0.006 {posix.close}
 2112    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {posix.read}
   12    0.001    0.000    0.007    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py:213(__init__)
   12    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py:265(open)
   12    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {posix.open}
 2112    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'bytearray' objects}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002   /usr/lib/python2.7/glob.py:18(glob)
   13    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/glob.py:29(iglob) 
   6523/6522    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {len}
    1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 /usr/lib/python2.7/glob.py:66(glob1)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py:45(filter)
   12    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py:297(_reconfigurePort)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/re.py:188(compile)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/re.py:226(_compile)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py:493(compile)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py:675(parse)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py:301(_parse_sub)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py:379(_parse)
   12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py:464(write)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py:478(_code)
      12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.readlink}
```

Thanks,
Rohith

Comment: Have you profiled this code? Are you sure that's where the slowdown is? I have a feeling the read/write file operations are where the slowdown is and not getting the value form the device.

Comment: No, i didnt do profiling and also i am not sure about read/write operation . but while using putty i didnt see any delay issuing the device command

Comment: Well I suggest taking a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) to pinpoint the slow down as opposed to just guessing.

Comment: Here is the profiler results:

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.001    0.001   54.605   54.605 /opt/lnx_attenTool/att_devices.py:49(scan_devices)
       12    0.009    0.001   54.522    4.543 {method 'readlines' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
     2136    0.020    0.000   54.513    0.026 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py:439(read)

Comment: Please edit your question as all formatting is lost in comments.

Comment: Added Profiler results

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: from the profiler read lines is taking long time for reading data from  serial port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the devices are independent; you could read their responses concurrently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from glob import glob
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import serial

def get_response(path):
    try:
        s = serial.Serial(path, 9600, timeout=2)
        s.write('XXXdeviceCommandToReadValue XXXX\r\n')
        return path, s.readlines(), None
    except Exception as e:
        return path, None, e

paths = glob('/dev/serial/by-id/usb-XXXXdevNAME*')
results = ThreadPool(min(len(paths), 20)).imap_unordered(get_response, paths)
for path, lines, error in results:
    print(path, lines, error) # handle results here
```

Assuming most of the time is spent on I/O, the code should complete much sooner.

Also, investigate whether `s.readlines()` is a proper API usage in this case (do you need `s.flush()` before it? Should you read a single line or a fixed number of bytes instead?). For an ordinary file/pipe, `.readlines()` will read all data until EOF. Check whether it makes sense for a serial device.